# Removing VCS from vcs_info prompt in zsh name to use ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY

Tags: format, zsh, prompt

I currently have this set up in my `.zshrc`

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook vcs_info
setopt prompt_subst
add-zsh-hook precmd vcs_info
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd

zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b%u%c'
```

and in my precmd function I set my RPROMPT to be `$(git_prompt_info)`. I also colour it based on the name of the branch (ie `main` might be blue, while `WIP` is red etc).

The issue I have is that it always prints out with a `git` prefix (like this `git:(main)`).

I checked the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#vcs_005finfo-Configuration) and it shows that from `:vcs_info:vcs-string:user-context:repo-root-name`the  relevant part I want to get rid of is `vcs-string` but I can't find a way to remove it.

I know I can just use `${vcs_info_msg_0_}` but I'm trying to incorporate `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN` and `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY` and haven't found a way to do so with `vcs_info`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to get access to the `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN` and `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY` parts of the prompt, you can just call directly into the zsh [code](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/07cdd7a53931a17a2c24f834c5e1ea0f62609c42/lib/git.zsh#L36-L61)

So now my prompt colouring is basically

```
  if [[  "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" != "" ]]
    then
      [[ "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" == "master" || "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" == "main" ]] && git2color='196'
      local git2="%B%F{${git2color}}(${vcs_info_msg_0_}$(parse_git_dirty))%f%b "
  fi
```